# debugging de consultas SQL en PHP (var_dump y debugDumpParams)

Tags: php, sql, pdo, php7

Cuando estamos escribiendo nuestras consultas SQL, podemos necesitar revisar como se están comportando los datos dinámicos que le enviamos, para validar que el resultado sea el esperado

**EJEMPLO**

Tengo el siguiente script para traer todos los posts de un determinado usuario trabajando 2 tablas por medio de un `JOIN`

```
<?php

$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog;port=3309", "root", "password");

$id = 1;

$consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT nameUser, namePost
                                FROM users
                                JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id
                                WHERE users.id = :id");
$consulta->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$consulta->execute();

var_dump($consulta);
```

Sin embargo si yo quiero hacer el volcado desde consola la consulta SQL que se esta armando por el dato dinámico que llega por `$id` podemos hacer lo siguiente

```
var_dump($consulta);
```

**RESULTADO**

```
object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
  string(96) "SELECT nameUser, namePost FROM users JOIN posts ON users.id 
= posts.user_id WHERE users.id = :id"
}
```

---

o también puedes hacer uso de `debugDumpParams` que te dará una estructura similar a la siguiente

```
SQL: [82] SELECT nameUser, namePost
    FROM users
    JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id
    WHERE users.id  = ?
Params:  2
Key: Position #0:
paramno=0
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=1
Key: Position #1:
paramno=1
id=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
```

> Esta última opción me esta mostrando también que al final hay un valor
>   dinámico, sin embargo no se muestra exactamente cual es ese valor,
>   para comprobar si es el que se debe recibir

¿Cómo podría hacer para que en este último caso, pueda ver en lugar del marcador de nombre/posición, el valor directo que se esta mandando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde la versión 7.2 de PHP, la función `debugDumpParams()` además de mostrar la consulta SQL mandada, agrega la posibilidad de ver los valores dinámicos que se le están enviando, es decir vas a poder visualizar en vez de `:id` esto `12` que sería el valor que el usuario este mandando

**EJEMPLO**

```
$consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT nameUser, namePost FROM users 
                               JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id 
                               WHERE users.id = :id");
$consulta->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$consulta->execute();
```

Sin embargo si ahora ejecuto la consulta siguiente:

```
var_dump($consulta->debugDumpParams());
```

Obtendré un resultado similar al siguiente

```
SQL: [96] SELECT nameUser, namePost FROM users JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id WHERE users.id = :id
Sent SQL: [94] SELECT nameUser, namePost FROM users JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id WHERE users.id = 1
Params:  1
Key: Name: [3] :id
paramno=-1
name=[3] ":id"
is_param=1
param_type=1
NULL
```

*OBSERVACIONES*

> 1. Manda primero la consulta SQL con el marcador de posición/nombre
> 2. Seguido manda la consulta SQL pero en lugar de los marcadores, manda el valor dinámico que le esta llegando por medio de alguna
>      variable
> 3. Esto funcionará solo si la **emulación de sentencias preparadas esta activada**